# Matlab: Increase bar chart area for long tick labels when saving

Tags: matlab, charts, save, latex, axis-labels

I have a bar chart with x-labels that are quite long.

How do I save the figure such that the labels don't get cut off like below - do I just scale it down? Also is it possible to save it as a cropped pdf to the figure and labels only so that I can use it in Latex?

[image]

Comment: Please post a runnable example that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to move up the axis (and, if needed, to reduce its size to fit in the figure).

```
pos = get(gca,'position');

set(gca,'position',[pos(1) pos(2) + 0.1 pos(3) * 0.95 pos(4) * 0.95])
```

This applies if "`unit`" property is set to "`normalized`", if not the scaling factors should be defined accordingly to the "`unit`" mode

You can also reduce the size of the fonts (default value should be 10)

```
set(gca,'fontsize',8)
```

Hope this helps.